# How can I use decltype as the template parameter for a return type of a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

See the following code

```
    template <typename T> 
    struct Node
    {
      T data;
      Node<T>* left;
      Node<T>* right;

      Node (T d, Node<T>* l = nullptr, Node<T>* r = nullptr) : data(d), left(l), right(r) {}
    };

    template <typename ItType>
    auto buildBinaryTree (ItType start, ItType end) -> Node<decltype(*start)>* // doesn't like this line
    {
      // implementation removed for simplicity of post as the signature is the issue
    }

    template <typename T> 
    Node<T>* buildBinaryTree (std::vector<T>& v)
    {
      if  ( v.empty() )
       return nullptr; 

      std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
      return buildBinaryTree (v.begin(), v.end()); 
    }

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
  Node<int>* root = buildBinaryTree ( v );
```

Basically what is the best way to implement the following signature as I am getting a compile error

> ```
> main.cpp:81:10: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'Node<int> *'
>       with an rvalue of type 'Node<decltype(* start)> *'
>   return buildBinaryTree (v.begin(), v.end());
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the nicest solution, if you are using the containers of the standard library, is the following:

```
template <typename ItType>
auto buildBinaryTree (ItType start, ItType end) -> Node<typename ItType::value_type>*
```

**UPDATE:** We need an extra level of indirection with `value_type` as follows: `std::iterator_traits<ItType>::value_type` (kindly [pointed out by Praetorian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060787/how-can-i-use-decltype-as-the-template-parameter-for-a-return-type-of-a-template/20060954?noredirect=1#comment29882026_20060954)).

---

Another solution is to change

```
auto buildBinaryTree (ItType start, ItType end) -> Node<decltype(*start)>*
```

to this (You may need to `#include <type_traits>`):

```
auto buildBinaryTree (ItType start, ItType end) -> Node<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*start)>::type>*
```

The gcc error message was clear:

> error: cannot convert `Node<int&>*` to `Node<int>*` in return

apparently, you are using clang, which, unfortunately, doesn't give such a clear error message... :(

Comment: The `typename ItType::value_type` solution will fail if the iterator type happens to be a raw pointer, which even standard library containers are allowed to have. You need the extra level of indirection by wrapping it in `std::iterator_traits<ItType>::value_type` to make the code portable.

Comment: @Praetorian Many thanks for pointing that out; fixed that in the answer.

Comment: yes @Ali I was doing this on a mac :), I use gcc on linux at home :). That compiler error definitely would have solved the issue. Thanks again for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Node<typename std::decay<decltype(*start)>::type> *
```

You need to `#include <type_traits>`.

A cleaner solution might be to use `std::iterator_traits<ItType>::value_type`, though.

Comment: To elaborate, the problem is that `*start` is an lvalue and not an identifier so its `decltype` yields a reference type. `decay` removes the reference.

Comment: Thanks @Potatoswatter this helps to clarify this further.